# Function called within a function not working

Tags: javascript

Im going to post it as I can not find the answer how to fix that.

I have the following code where I change background color for some divs.
I have a function for that changeSqColor() which doesn't work when called within another function.
What is the problem here?
(array colors are defined and the number of elements = number of the divs)

```
var squares = document.getElementsByClassName("square");

function changeSqColor() {
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
    }
}

changeSqColor(); // this works ok colors are changes

function resetGame() {
    //other commands
    changeSqColor(); //this one doesnt work, in console it says 'undefined'
}
```

Comment: Where the call to `resetGame`? Maybe when it is called the element isn't on the DOM?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) That code seems like it should work. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). *"in console it says 'undefined'"* Show us **exactly** what it says.

Comment: resetGame is called at:
    resetButton.addEventListener("click", resetGame);
this is ok as other commands within this function work fine

Comment: are you sure colors[i] exists? you are using the same counter for both elements and colors

Comment: I strongly recommend reading this article:
https://dmitripavlutin.com/6-ways-to-declare-javascript-functions/

You will learn how to declare and invoke javascript functions :)

Comment: colors[i] exists. i made a commit to github at github.com/allVentures/Color_Guessing_Game can u have a look at that?

Answer (score 1):

You should have to call `function resetGame` sometimes in your code. You haven't invoked `resetGame` .

```js
var squares = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
let colors = ['red','green','blue','white','yellowgreen'];
function changeSqColor() {
  for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
     squares[i].style.background = colors[i]; 
   }
setTimeout(function(){resetGame();},3000);// call resetGame Function.
}
changeSqColor(); 

function resetGame (){
 for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].style.background = colors[0]; 
  }
  setTimeout(function(){changeSqColor();},3000);
  // As you mentioned calling changeSqColor() 
}
```

```html
<div class="square">1</div>
<div class="square">2</div>
<div class="square">3</div>
<div class="square">4</div>
<div class="square">5</div>
```

Comment: 'function resetGame (){
 for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
squares[i].style.background = colors[i];}
}'
when i have this reset function defined like that it is ok and works fine.
i just want to reuse the code as I use in some  other parts of the appliacation:
Thats why I put it into the changeSqColor() which dosnt work when called from the resetGame function

Comment: @PawelSzewczyk see the edit . You can invoke every other functions from inside other function.

Comment: i think you dont understand my question.
i see the edit; and this is what I wanna avoid.
you put:
  for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];}
back into the resetGame function.
i dont wanna do that, I wanna call the function changeSqColor();  which contains exacly the same code;
I know that if i restype the code into the resetGame function it will work.
But this is not the point here.
My question was why cant I call the changeSqColor() to change the colors?

Comment: @PawelSzewczyk `for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) { squares[i].style.background = colors[0];} ` is only for reset the color . You can see there after `changeSqColor` is invoked and put all the colors again.

Comment: ok, understand, but it doesnt work for me. The changeSqColor() is not executed.
Why?

Comment: @PawelSzewczyk there might be problem with `//other commands` . If you show those.

Comment: i made a commit to github at https://github.com/allVentures/Color_Guessing_Game can u have a look at that?

Answer (score 0):

changeSqColor(); - This works because you are explicitly executing the method call by () brackets.

resetGame()  you are just defining method by not executing it. if you want to  define the function resetGame() as well execute it in one go, we can do it as,

```
(function resetGame() {
    //other commands
    changeSqColor(); //this one doesnt work, in console it says 'undefined'
})()
```

if you are calliing resetGame() method then 'undefined' will come if your function changeSqColor() is not in scope/accessible while resetGame() is getting executed.

Comment: I execute it when i click on element:
    resetButton.addEventListener("click", resetGame);
and other commands within the resetGame functions are executer, only the function changeSqColor();  is not; so this is not the problem here ;-)

Comment: I think then just for the time being move the function definition of changeSqColor  just on the top of resetGame and see if it getting the method. Problem seems to while resetGame is getting executed changeSqColor  is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i know what was the problem.
i declared local variable as a new place for colors.

before

```
function resetGame (){
var colors = generateRandomColors(6);
pickedColor = pickColor();
colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
messageDisplay.textContent = "";
changeSqColor();
}
```

after:

```
function resetGame (){
colors = generateRandomColors(6); // var removed
pickedColor = pickColor();
colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
messageDisplay.textContent = "";
changeSqColor();
}
```

stupid mistake ;-)